# Include binary from relative path in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

I have a `project/bin/` directory which is not included in the `PATH`. It contains 
the binaries `project/bin/one` and `project/bin/two`.

A bash script is located in `project/shell/script1/run.sh`. Now, I want to use the binary from the `project/bin` folder in the `project/shell/script1/run.sh` script. I would like to have a global script which can be `source`d, and include those binaries automatically.

So, I created a script `project/bin/load_bin`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

$local_bin_one='./one'
$local_bin_two='./two'
```

In my `project/shell/script1/run.sh` I execute the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source '../../bin/load_bin'
```

However, when I try to use `$local_bin_one` I get a file not found error. This is because the `$local_bin_one` points to `./one` instead of `../../bin/one`.

**Question:** How can I find the path of the script that is calling `source '../../bin/load_bin'` from the `project/bin/load_bin` script itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the path of a Bash script this way:

```
${0%/*}
```

That is, take `$0` (`argv[0]`, the full path and filename the script was invoked with), and strip off the last slash and what comes after that (equivalent to `$(dirname "$0")`).

You can then do this:

```
mydir=${0%/*}
source "$mydir/../../bin/load_bin"
```

Or you can even do this:

```
cd ${0%/*}
source '../../bin/load_bin'
```

Comment: Thank you. But my problem is, that I've no idea in the `load_bin` script, who the caller of `source "$mydir/../../bin/load_bin"` is. If I execute `dirname` it only shows `.` because source just takes the code and pastes it into the calling script.

Comment: In this case I think you should set an environment variable to some well-understood "root" like the directory where `load_bin` is, before sourcing it.